# Inserting wrapping child element with lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am trying to insert a child element in an element that would have the same text as their former parent, so a wrapping child. The basic example, that is my input:

```
<p>
    <s>text</s>
    <s>text</s>
    <s>text</s>
</p>
```

I would like something like that (the content of anno would come from a NLP tool, not really important):

```
<p>
    <s>
        <orig>text</orig>
        <anno>token1</anno>
    </s>
    <s>
        <orig>text</orig>
        <anno>token2</anno>
    </s>
    <s>
        <orig>text</orig>
        <anno>token3</anno>
    </s>
</p>
```

The anno element would be easier, what I don't get is to make a child element inside  that contains the text  used to have.

Using different element functions (addprevious, addnext, append, insert) I get to make things like:

```
    <s>text<orig/></s>
    <s>text<orig>text</orig></s>
    <orig><s>text</s></orig>
```

But none of this is what I want. Do I have to work with replace? And in this case, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sys

from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse(open("/tmp/so.xml"))

# Make sure you have enough annos to match the existing <s> elements.
annos = ["token1", "token2", "token3"]

for i, s in enumerate(tree.xpath("//s")):
    # remember the text of the <s>
    text = s.text

    # remove the <s> from its parent
    parent = s.getparent()
    parent.remove(s)

    # create a new <s>
    new_s = etree.SubElement(parent, "s")

    # create the <orig>, set the remembered text on it
    orig = etree.SubElement(new_s, "orig")
    orig.text = text

    # create the <anon>, set the token on it
    annon = etree.SubElement(new_s, "anon")
    annon.text = annos[i]

with open("/tmp/out.xml", "wb") as f:
    tree.write(f, pretty_print=True)
```

Output:

```
<p>
  <s>
    <orig>text</orig>
    <anon>token1</anon>
  </s>
  <s>
    <orig>text</orig>
    <anon>token2</anon>
  </s>
  <s>
    <orig>text</orig>
    <anon>token3</anon>
  </s>
</p>
```

Comment: Ok, so saving text, geting parent, deleting element and then creating new child elements. Perfects, thanks a lot! :)